# UITextFiled don't show clearButton sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I add a simple UITableView to my project,and every cell include a UITextField with clearButtonMode = **UITextFieldViewModeAlways**.
but strange issue occurs .when I reloadData,some textfield **don't show clear button**.

so I grab the part and build a sample and never find this issue.
I just wonder is some property has a effect to the textField.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"userIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    for (UIView *sv in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [sv removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    tf.text = [self.tb_data[indexPath.row];
    tf.rightViewMode   = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    tf.tag = indexPath.row+100;
    tf.delegate = self;

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:tf];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag >= 100) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag >= 100) {

        [self.tb_data removeObjectAtIndex:textField.tag-100];
        [self.tb beginUpdates];
        [self.tb deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag-100 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect frame = self.tb.frame;
                             frame.size.height = 40*self.tb_data.count;
                             self.tb.frame = frame;
                     }];
        [self.tb endUpdates];
        [self.tb reloadData];

    }
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Instead of `cell.bounds` give a custom arbitrary frame like CGRectMake(0,0,100,90)and check.

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR you're right!Thank you. clear button beyond the bounds

Comment: you are welcome @passol. Please note the layout of cell is done post the delegate call cellForRowAtIndex Path, and until that time the frame would be `CGRectZero` unless explicitly modified.